# TFS and Git - Making users be limited to push code

Tags: git, tfs, push, restrictions

We are using TFS as project management interface and we are using Git for managing the repository.

We want users be limited to push a file and push to branch in the repository.

For example:
*In branch A, user1 can not make changes to file1, user2 can not make changes to file2, user3 can change every file in the branch etc.*

Is it possible in TFS?

Comment: we cannot exactly  set the restriction as you mentioned, we can only set the permission accordingly based on the exist settings, please see the similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989974/how-can-i-allow-only-certain-people-to-commit-in-visual-studio-online

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible in TFS?

Not that I know.

What you can do is setup an intermediate repository which will act as a gatekeeper: if the push succeed, that repo ([through a post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive)) will push to the actual target: the TFS Git repo.

That intermediate repo should be managed by an authorization layer like **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)**: gitolite can limit pushes to a branch or even a file: see "[restricting pushes by dir/file name](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref-2/#restricting-pushes-by-dirfile-name)"

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see you possibly doing this is through a [TFS server-side plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWj-JU0Fu3c&feature=youtu.be). You can implement an [`ISubscriber`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server.isubscriber.aspx) that subscribes to the Git [`PushNotification`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.git.server.pushnotification(v=vs.120).aspx) event. This will allow you to inspect the pushed commits and block the push if your policies aren't satisfied. You will have to define your branch/user restrictions in some structured format outside of TFS however.

I have used this project successfully, which provides a nice framework for implementing policies on pushes to a TFS-hosted Git repo:

https://github.com/giuliov/GitPushFilterPlugin

The only caveat (from my own experience) is that the amount of data available in the `PushNotification` event may not be sufficient to determine which branches the [`IncludedCommits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.git.server.pushnotification.includedcommits(v=vs.120).aspx) pertain to.